# java result set only writing one line instead of all selected into .csv

Tags: java, mysql, csv, resultset, jlist

I have a java function that is meant to take strings from jlist called "readyList" and pulling data from mysql workbench tables with the intent to write a line for each string in a .csv file. With the current code it sucessfully pulls the data one at a time like i intended but it only writes the last line instead of all the lines. I want to have all the lines written in the .csv file. Please help!

```
int[] selectedIx = readyList.getSelectedIndices(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedIx.length; i++) {
      //  while (i < selectedIx.length) {
           Object sel = readyList.getModel().getElementAt(selectedIx[i]);

    Statement s1 = DBConnect.connection.createStatement();
    String selTable01 = "SELECT Sku As s, Qty As q, Orig_Retail As prce, Orig_Sku As orgsk, Store As strcd "
                + "FROM completed_lines WHERE Form_Name = '" + sel + "' AND Warranty = 'true'";

        s1.execute(selTable01);
        try (ResultSet rs01 = s1.getResultSet()) {
            fWriter = new FileWriter("Exports/Transfers/" + /* frmNm.replace(":", "_") */"EBW_" + GtDates.fdate + ".csv", false);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
            String header = "slip_number,slip_type,out_store,in_store,item_number,quantity,price,comment,to_num";
            writer.write(header);  
            writer.newLine();
            while (rs01.next()) {
                String strcode = rs01.getString("strcd");
                String sku = rs01.getString("s");
                String qty = rs01.getString("q");
                String price = rs01.getString("prce");
                String orgsku = rs01.getString("orgsk");
                //System.out.println(frmNm.split("_")[1] + qty + "," + sku + "," + vendor + "," + desc1 + "," + reas + "," + descdmg + "," + orgR + "," + nwsku + "," + desc2 + "," + qtyI);
                String line = ""+","+"out"+","+strcode+","+"RTV"+","+sku+","+qty+","+price+","+"EBW"+","+orgsku;
                writer.write(line);
                writer.newLine();

            }
        } 
      //   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "All Data from Selected Forms has been Exported");
    }
       //  FormCompelted();
```

writer.close();

```
}
```

}

Comment: where and how do you declare `writer` and `fwriter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues with this code. The reason you're only getting the last result is because of this line:

```
fWriter = new FileWriter("Exports/Transfers/" + /* frmNm.replace(":", "_") */"EBW_" + GtDates.fdate + ".csv", false);
```

This line is inside your loop. The `false` as the last parameter tells `FileWriter` not to append. In other words, a `false` means overwrite the file if it exists. Since this is in your loop, each result overwrites the file that the last result created. You should create the `FileWriter` outside of your loop, probably in a try with resources. That will allow you to remove your `writer.close()` call, which should have been in a `finally` block anyway.

Not related to your original question but something you should be aware of: You're creating a new `Statement` with each loop iteration. This can be an expensive operation. You should use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead. Create it outside your loop and then just set the parameter and execute it inside the loop. It also implements `AutoCloseable`, so you can create it in a try with resources too, probably the same one you create your `FileWriter` in.

Comment: After checking the few suggestions and talking to my boss, I figured out that this function is doing exactly what it suppose to do and I wanted it to do more. the "sel" object is suppose to pull a specific string from the readyList and pull all the data from the database that matches sel, and it does that beautifully. I wanted this function to pull from different multiple strings from the list and pull data from different lines where the different strings match.

Comment: I thinking of making another counter loop with that function nested inside and the outer loop would pull the different strings and assign it to "sel" then the function does its job. Can I tweak the existing loop or copy it with slight tweaks to make it work? What do you think?